# How do I send a custom parameter to a custom exception in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, custom-exceptions, custom-error-handling

I want to send my own parameters into custom exception using throw new CustomException.

I've defined my own error codes into Config and these are necessary for me.

```
public function saveMenu($data){
    $validatedData = Validator::make($data, array(
        'id' => 'required',
        'menuID' => 'required',


    ));
    try {
        $validatedData->validate();
    } catch \Exception $e){

        $data= array(
            'status' => false,
            'code' => 599
            'message' => config('exception_codes.599').'<br/>'.$validatedData->errors(),
            'data' => []
        );

       throw new CustomException($data ['message'], $data['code'],$e);
        return $data;
    }
```

}

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

```
protected $dontReport = [
    //
];

protected $dontFlash = [
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
];


public function report( Exception $exception=NULL)
{


    parent::report($exception);
}

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

}

```
class CustomException extends Exception{

 public $code;
public $message;
public $trace;

public function __construct( $message, $code, Exception $exception=NULL)

{
    parent::__construct($message, $code, $exception);
    $this->code = $code;
    $this->message=$message;
    $this->trace= $exception->getTrace();
}
public function report($message, $code, Exception $exception=NULL)
{
    $message = $exception->getMessage();
    $xx= new Menu();
    $xx->setFile($this->trace[1]['file']);
    $xx->setLine($this->trace[1]['line']);
    $xx->setFunction($this->trace[1]['function']);
    $xx->setClass($this->trace[1]['class']);
    $xx->setMessage($message);
    $xx->save();
    parent::report($exception);

}

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I get this error;

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Exceptions\CustomException::report(), 0 passed in
>   C:......\Handler.php on line 102 and at least 2 expected"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to pass in the message and code explicitly in the `report()` method.

```
public function report()
{
    $message = $this->getMessage();

    $hataTakip = new HataTakip();
    $hataTakip->setFile($this->trace[1]['file']);
    $hataTakip->setLine($this->trace[1]['line']);
    $hataTakip->setFunction($this->trace[1]['function']);
    $hataTakip->setClass($this->trace[1]['class']);
    $hataTakip->setMessage($message);
    $hataTakip->save();

    parent::report($this);

}
```

In any case, you should check out the documentation en [Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#renderable-exceptions).

Comment: it says Call to undefined method Exception::report()  @Mozammil